# Display text to next activity kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I was looking for my problem on the internet, but the solutions given still do not work.
How to transfer data from first Activity to second?(plain text)

MainActivity

```
 btn.setOnClickListener {
        val player1= findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et1) as EditText
        val player2= findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et2) as EditText

        val intent1= Intent(this, MainActivity3::class.java).apply {
            putExtra("player1",player1.getText().toString())
            putExtra("player2",player2.getText().toString())
        }
        startActivity(intent1)
    }
```

Second Activity

```
fun PlayGame(cellID:Int,buSelected:Button){

    val playe1= intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE)
    val playe2= intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE)

    val textView2= findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2).apply{
        text= playe1
        text=playe2
    }

    if(ActivePlayer==1){
        textView2.setText(": $playe1")
        buSelected.text="0"
        buSelected.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue)
        player1.add(cellID)
        ActivePlayer=2
    }else{
        textView2.setText(": $playe2")
        buSelected.text="X"
        buSelected.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green)
        player2.add(cellID)
        ActivePlayer=1
    }

    buSelected.isEnabled=false
    CheckWiner()
}
```

I want the player's name from MainActivity goes to Second ;p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a sharedpreferences, in your next activity after saving the values to a Val or var delete the shared preferences continue.

It’s not ideal but it just may get you to where you can at least interact with that data.

I used this method for something similar last night. If I have time tonight I was going to post a how to on this on my website. If I can I’ll swing by here and edit my answer.  With code and explanation unless you get it figured out by then.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the way you get your values. Try this:

```
val playe1= intent.getStringExtra("player1")
val playe2= intent.getStringExtra("player2")
```

Comment: What are you seeing?